# Why segmentation fault in this HashTable code in Vala?

Tags: segmentation-fault, hashtable, vala

I am trying following code of creating and showing a simple HashTable in Vala:

```
public static void myshowHashTable(HashTable sht){   
    stdout.printf("Size of sent hashtable: %d", (int)sht.size()); 
    sht.foreach((key,val) => {
            stdout.printf("Key:%s, value:%s", (string)key, (string)val);
        }
    ); 
}

public static void main(string[] args){
        HashTable<string,int> ht = new HashTable<string,int>(str_hash, str_equal); 
        ht.insert ("first string", 1);
        ht.insert ("second string", 2);
        ht.insert ("third string", 3);
        myshowHashTable(ht); 
}
```

Above code compiles with following warnings:

```
myhashtable.vala.c: In function ‘myshowHashTable’:
myhashtable.vala.c:45:29: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘g_hash_table_foreach’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   45 |  g_hash_table_foreach (sht, ___lambda4__gh_func, NULL);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             |
      |                             void (*)(const void *, const void *, void *)
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:50,
                 from myhashtable.vala.c:4:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghash.h:105:61: note: expected ‘GHFunc’ {aka ‘void (*)(void *, void *, void *)’} but argument is of type ‘void (*)(const void *, const void *, void *)’
  105 |                                             GHFunc          func,
      |                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

When I run the executable created, it give following error:

```
$ ./myhashtable
Segmentation fault
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get about compilation warnings, but segmentation fault is pretty clear: you have HashTable<string,int>, but try to print (string)key, (string)val.

And you omit type specialization at sht argument. Therefore compiler couldn't deduce types.

I got it not crashing this way:

```
public static void myshowHashTable(HashTable<string,int> sht){   
    stdout.printf("Size of sent hashtable: %d\n", (int)sht.size()); 
    sht.foreach((key,val) => {
            stdout.printf("Key:%s, value:%d\n", key, val);
        }
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Why `(string)val` cannot convert integer to string? I need it to be converted to string further ahead in the program.

Comment: Because Vala is not Go, not Python and not Java. Vala is almost syntax sugar for C. `val` doesn't contain type information on its own, therefore there is no way to recognize in runtime how to convert it.

Comment: Can such segmentation faults be dangerous and lead to loss of disk data?

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't relate to Vala. If you didn't call 'sync', you can't be sure your data are copied from OS disk cache to disk, so if power were off you loose it. If you didn't call 'flush', data were not copied from application buffers to OS disk cache, so if there was segfault you loose it. Is it called "loss of disk data"? I don't call it this way because data are not on disk yet.